# APEX - Parsing a recursive JSON

Tags: json, parsing, recursion, apex

I am programming to salesforce (APEX).
The input is complex and recursive JSON. Something like

```
{
    "id":"0",
    "children":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "children":[...]
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "children":[...]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need a way to iterate a complex and recursive JSON (in APEX).

anyone can help?

Thanks,

Hagai

Answer (score 0):

If you know the names of all the attributes in your JSON object, you can create classes to represent them and then deserialize.  For instance:

```
public class myObject {
  public String id;
  public List<myObject> children;
}
```

Then write a method that returns the children

```
static List<myObject> getChildren(myObject parent){
    List<myObject> children = new List<myObject>();
    for ( myObject c : parent.children ){
        children.addAll( getChildren(c) );
        children.add(c);
    }
    return children;
}
```

And finally put the two together:

```
myObject parent = (myObject)JSON.deserialize(jsonString,myObject.class);
List<myObject> all = new List<myObject>();
all.add(parent);
all.addAll(getChildren(parent));
```